# Correct way of applying bindings multiple times

Tags: knockout.js

I am refactoring some existing code to use Knockout. The code in question is a calendar, and is dynamically built as the user pages through previous and subsequent months or weeks.

The way the calendar works is when the user presses next or previous, the container than renders it is cleared and then rebuilt.

Getting Knockout working was easy, just a matter of applying the right `data-bind` arguments on the cell and then calling `ko.applyBindings`.

My concern is that because the code destroys the DOM elements that Knockout is bound to, that it is leaking memory. Is this the case, and if so, what should the calendar be doing before clearing the container containing the bindings?

Comment: Have you used your browser's [developer tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/) to check your assumptions? Generally, if you use knockout to construct your DOM, you shouldn't touch it unless it's through a binding handler. Use `with`, `if`, `template` and `foreach` bindings to dynamically add *and* remove parts of your UI.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you do not need to apply bindings multiple times. You create a model, choose a DOM node, and apply bindings to it. If somewhat is changing in the model during the application life time, this changes are reflected on the markup via notifications of observable or computed properties of the model has been changed.

But if you are injecting knockout component into another application, that manages the node the knockout bindings has been applied to, you can clean node from knockout bindings:

```
var element = document.getElementById("MyNodeId");
ko.cleanNode(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Don't use the cleanNode function to rebind a model - instead make the
>   model an observable too.

Taken from [Jef Claes blog](http://www.jefclaes.be/2014/04/rebinding-knockout-viewmodel.html), I've been using this concept to rebind model, instead of using `cleanNode`.

Sample code

```
<div id="books">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: bookModel().booksImReading">
        <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
    </ul>
</div>

var page = {
    bookModel : ko.observable({
        booksImReading: [
            { name: "Effective Akka" }, 
            { name: "Node.js the Right Way" }]
    })
};

ko.applyBindings(page, elementToBind);

page.bookModel({
    booksImReading: [
        { name: "SQL Performance Explained" },
        { name: "Code Connected" }]
});
```